# Why can't I use file:// in html a tag with href attribute?

Tags: html, file, href

I am trying to redirect to a page which lists files using file protocol in HTML `<a>` tag using `href` attribute as follow:

```
<a href="file:///var/www/html/" target="_blank">Files</a>
```

The reason I am doing this is to list all the files in my apache document root, as simply going to `/`will open `index.html`, which I would not like to disturb (this behaviour is useful to me) and I cannot use server-side scripting like PHP.

Comment: Because that represents a file on the client's computer, not on the server.

Comment: You can do it with `ftp://` URI scheme with allowing access to everybody on a browser. `file:///` refers to a local file as @FedericoklezCulloca pointed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure apache to list the file instead of serving the index.html file.
You can configure this only in certain path

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
  Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

but still this will cause the problem of not serving the index.html file (if it's not present).
So you have to decide if you want your server to serve the index file or show the list....